# React onChange cannot be triggered by AJAX data

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a ZipCode component which has 3 fields: zip code, city and state. The component should has 2 features (please see the pic): 
1. If users have the location data already (fetches from the database and passed down by its parent component), it should show default location values
2. If users input new zip code, it will trigger another third party API call to fetch city and state info and fill out those two fields automatically.

Right now, the issue is when I populate zip code field in one place, it will auto fill the city, state in all other components. I figured out, it might because the onChange function cannot be triggered when getting new location data from the third party API. It only can be triggered by typing some info.

Some of my code is here:

```
19: class ZipCode extends Component {
20:   constructor(props) {
21:     super(props);
22:     this.state = {
23:       zipCode: props.zipCode || '',
24:       city: props.city || '',
25:       state: props.state || '',
26:       newZipCode: '',
27:       newCity: '',
28:       newState: '',
29:       showError: false,
30:     };
31: 
32:     this.handleZipChange = this.handleZipChange.bind(this);
33:     this.handleCityChange = this.handleCityChange.bind(this);
34:     this.handleStateChange = this.handleStateChange.bind(this);
35:   }
36: 
37:   componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
38:     const { city, state, zipCode } = nextProps.zipCodeData;
39:     // zipCodeData from state:
40:     // const initialState = fromJS({
41:     //   zipCodeData: {
42:     //     zipCode: '',
43:     //     city: '',
44:     //     state: '',
45:     //   },
46:     // });
47:     this.setState({
48:       zipCode: this.props.zipCode,
49:       state: this.props.state,
50:       city: this.props.city,
51:       newCity: city,
52:       newZipCode: zipCode,
53:       newState: state,
54:     });
55:   }
56: 
57:   shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
58:     return !_.isEqual(nextProps.zipCodeData, this.props.zipCodeData) || !_.isEqual(nextState, this.state);
59:   }
60: 
61: 
62:   handleZipChange(zipCode) {
63:     const { dispatchZipCode } = this.props;
64:     console.log('handleZipChange ZipCode', zipCode);
65:     this.setState({
66:       newZipCode: zipCode,
67:       zipCode: '',
68:       showError: true,
69:     }, () => {
70:       if (zipCode.length === 5) {
71:         this.setState({
72:           showError: false,
73:         });
74:         dispatchZipCode({ zipCode });
75:       }
76:     });
77:   }
78: 
79:   handleCityChange(newCity) {
80:     console.log(newCity); // not working unless typing
81:     this.setState({
82:       ...this.state,
83:       newCity,
84:     });
85:   }
86: 
87:   handleStateChange(e) {
88:     console.log(e); // not working unless typing
89:   }
90: 
91:   render() {
92:     const { isRequired, notPublicDisclaimer, direction } = this.props;
93:     const { zipCode, city, state, newZipCode, newCity, newState, showError } = this.state;
94: 
95:     return (
96:       <Zc direction={direction}>
97:         <Zc.column>
98:           <Zc.input
99:             title={translations.ZIPCODE}
100:             notPublicDisclaimer={notPublicDisclaimer}
101:             isRequired={isRequired}
102:             placeholder={'01234'}
103:             showLabel
104:             value={newZipCode || zipCode}
105:             limit={5}
106:             handleOnTextChange={this.handleZipChange}
107:             direction={direction}
108:             showError={showError}
109:           />
110:           <Zc.error>
111:             { showError && <ErrorText text={'Please enter a valid Zip Code'} /> }
112:           </Zc.error>
113:         </Zc.column>
114:         <Zc.wrapper>
115:           <Zc.formFieldCity>
116:             <Zc.label direction={direction}>{translations.CITY}</Zc.label>
117:             {/* I use material design, but if changed to <input> and onChange, it will be the same */}
118:             <Zc.input
119:               placeholder={translations.CITY}
120:               value={newCity || city}
121:               readOnly
122:               direction={direction}
123:               handleOnTextChange={this.handleCityChange}
124:             />
125:           </Zc.formFieldCity>
126:           <Zc.formFieldState>
127:             <Zc.label direction={direction}>{translations.STATE}</Zc.label>
128:             <Zc.inputDisabled
129:               placeholder={translations.STATE}
130:               value={newState || state}
131:               readOnly
132:               direction={direction}
133:               onChange={this.handleStateChange}
134:             />
135:           </Zc.formFieldState>
136:         </Zc.wrapper>
137:       </Zc>
138:     );
139:   }
140: }
```

Does anyone knows how to avoid updating location info every where when using this component? Thank you so much~
[image]

[image]